# Use screen in the middle of a command chain starting with SSH

Tags: ssh, command-line, command

I need to launch a command that will:

1. Login to a server
2. Go to a specific directory
3. Attach a screen environment (already set up)
4. Start another command (does not really matter)

I tried doing this:

```
ssh {login}@{server} "cd /Where/I/Need/To/Be; screen -r MyScreenSession; MyFinalCommand"
```

Everything works fine but attaching to the screen session. How can I fix it?

Comment: "ssh user@server command" doesn't allocate a pty by default, which will probably confuse `screen` (which will want to know the dimensions of your terminal). Try using "ssh -t user@server...".

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I needed:

```
ssh -t {login}@{server} cd /Where/I/Need/To/Be; screen -S MyScreenSession -X stuff "MyFinalCommandWithoutSpace^M"
```

`-t` to ask `ssh` to [start a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245185/ssh-command-t-option)

`screen -S MyScreenSession -X stuff` will write inside a `[detached]`screen session.